# Help I can’t attach lenses to my Nikon

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount, equipment-damage, nikon-d800

I can’t seem to attach lenses to my Nikon d800 , not sure of the name of the part so calling it a lens attachment pin but it’s dropped inside the lens ring into the body and guessing this is why lenses won’t attach to the camera.

I’ve tried to fish it out with no joy , has it happened to anyone else?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to PSE. As a former professional who's used Nikon equipment (& lots of others, too) for almost 50 years now, it appears that there is nothing wrong with your D800's lens mount. The pin tip you can see in the small opening in the lens mounting ring is the internal autofocus drive mechanism. It engages with the lens once it's attached so it doesn't interfere with the mounting process. Can we please see an image of the rear of the lens or lenses you're not able to attach to see if that's where the problem lies?

Comment: Hi Karl thanks for the reply in trying to help, it’s unfortunate this has happened as I’ve had a break away from photography for a couple of years and this has happened two days later :(  it looks like what’s at fault is the pin that’s stuck inside the lens ring as I can’t lock the lens onto the camera . Googling Nikon d800 mirror under images you can see the pin is raised on comparative images , any ideas ? Typically this would break on a bank holiday too  :(

Comment: Just to add the lens detach button is stuck down unless I move the pin inside the lens ring , this releases the button

Comment: You should be able to manually depress the raised locking pin as it is spring loaded. If the pin is stuck in the up position, that would certainly prevent the lens from engaging with the on camera mount. Sorry, but I am unable to  determine what could prevent the lens release button from returning to its normal position while causing the locking pin to lock in the up position.

Comment: The lens retaining pin is clearly visible in the upper left of your photo and is protruding as it should. It is spring loaded and should retract when a lens is rotated over it and then pop back out when the lens is all of the way into position.

Answer (score 2):

That is the autofocus drive mechanism and it is *supposed to be* below the surface anytime the camera is not trying to focus a lens.

The lock/unlock pin is also raised as it is supposed to be; but you mentioned that the release button sticks in the down position. It is possible to bend the release pin so that it binds in the opening (I've done it).

Are you aligning the indicator marks (white dots)? The lens will only mount from one orientation.

Is the lens compatible? Some older lenses will bind on the aperture follower on the body (pre-AI lenses).

It appears that the mounting ring securing screws are all tight, but it is possible that there could be one (or more) loose/raised on the lens ring; and that could prevent mounting the lens.

It is also possible to bend a lens mounting ring (I've done it)... that can make mounting/unmounting very difficult.

Whatever the issue is; I *HIGHLY* recommend that you do not force a lens to mount, or mount a lens with a defective lock/unlock pin/button. If you manage to get a lens stuck onto the camera body the fix will be much more difficult and expensive (yeah, I've done that too).